# Почему таймер останавливается, выполнившись 1 раз

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, помогите  с таймером

При передвижении курсора мыши проверяется, если координата курсора по x меньше 50-ти, то переменная dx уменьшается до тех пор, пока переменная OutOfRangeне не станет  равна "OOR_N" (используется таймер setInterval),  но в результате выполнения     код внутри таймера выполняется один раз, в чем у меня ошибка?

```
canvas.onmousemove = mouseMove;

    function mouseMove(event){ 
    movecur();

}

function movecur(){
    var OutOfRange;
    if(curx<=50){
        OutOfRange="OOR_Y";

        function ChangeCanv() {

            timer1 = setInterval(Change(), 400);
        }

        function Change() {
            dx=dx-10;
            alert(dx);
            build();
            if (OutOfRange=="OOR_N"){
                clearInterval(timer1);
            }

        }
        ChangeCanv();
    }
    build();    
}
```

Comment: var OutOfRange - Отличное название для переменной! С функцией не спутаешь.

Answer (score 2):

вы отличаете вызов функции от её иемни?

```
setInterval(Change(), 400);
```

это вы вызвали функцию и передали `undefined` в `setInterval`

а надо было:

```
setInterval(Change, 400);
```