# Функция setInterval() выполняется только 1 раз

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется следующий код, который находится после /body> и перед /html>. После загрузки выполняется только один раз. Вопрос: почему и как это исправить?

```
function increaseTimer() {
    seconds++;
    if(seconds >= 60)
    {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if(minutes >= 60)
        {
            hours++;
            if(hours >= 24)
            {
                console.log("Stopping timer");
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }
    }
    var secStr = seconds >= 10 ? seconds.toString() : "0"+seconds.toString();
    var hrsStr = hours >= 10 ? hours.toString() : "0"+hours.toString();
    var minStr = minutes >= 10 ? minutes.toString() : "0"+minutes.toString();
    result = hrsStr + ":"+minStr+":"+secStr;
    document.getElementById("timecell").innerHTML = result;
    console.log(result);
}
var seconds = 0;
var minutes = 0;
var hours = 0;
var result = "";
var timer;
window.onload = function () {
    timer = setInterval(increaseTimer(),1000);
}
```

Полный файл на https://github.com/mcstarioni/mygithubpage/blob/master/Header.html

Comment: первый параметр setInterval - это строка или функция, а ты вместо передачи функции вызываешь ее сразу

Comment: Возможно дубликат вопроса: [Почему таймер останавливается, выполнившись 1 раз](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/176791/186999)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Измените

```
setInterval(increaseTimer(),1000);
```

на

```
setInterval(increaseTimer,1000);
```

потому что в первом случае интервал получает не функцию, а результат ее выполнения

Comment: Спасибо, работает.